# UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification is called twice when autocorrecting Chinese characters

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, autocorrect, uikeyboardtype

I have init method where I’m setting my observer,

```
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                        selector:@selector(textChanged:)
                                            name:UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification
                                          object:textField];
```

So when user enters Chinese characters from autocorrect it calls below method twice but when I enter english letter from keyboard it called this below method only once,

```
- (void)textChanged:(NSNotification *)notification
{

}
```

Any idea how can I avoid this?

---

Hi I did some backtrace for autocorrect chinese character & english character, they did different process.

backtrace for autocorrect chinese character

## 1 enter

```
  frame #6: 0x0000000102dfb109 Foundation`-[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 66
  frame #7: 0x0000000104585ab8 UIKit`-[UITextField fieldEditorDidChange:] + 257
  frame #8: 0x0000000104590cb7 UIKit`-[UITextInputController _sendDelegateChangeNotificationsForText:selection:] + 138
  frame #9: 0x0000000104598751 UIKit`-[UITextInputController setMarkedText:selectedRange:] + 744
  frame #10: 0x0000000103d1e200 UIKit`-[UIFieldEditor setMarkedText:selectedRange:] + 38
  frame #11: 0x00000001045896bb UIKit`-[UITextField setMarkedText:selectedRange:] + 90
  frame #12: 0x0000000104144c4a UIKit`-[UIResponder(UITextInput_Internal) _setMarkedText:selectedRange:] + 91
  frame #13: 0x0000000103e432f8 UIKit`-[UIKeyboardImpl unmarkText:] + 167
  frame #14: 0x0000000103e45df6 UIKit`__59-[UIKeyboardImpl handleAcceptedCandidate:executionContext:]_block_invoke_2 + 39
```

## 2 enter

```
  frame #6: 0x0000000102dfb109 Foundation`-[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 66
  frame #7: 0x0000000104585ab8 UIKit`-[UITextField fieldEditorDidChange:] + 257
  frame #8: 0x0000000104590cb7 UIKit`-[UITextInputController _sendDelegateChangeNotificationsForText:selection:] + 138
  frame #9: 0x000000010458970e UIKit`-[UITextField unmarkText] + 48
  frame #10: 0x0000000104144d8a UIKit`-[UIResponder(UITextInput_Internal) _unmarkText] + 61
  frame #11: 0x0000000103e43203 UIKit`-[UIKeyboardImpl unmarkText] + 43
  frame #12: 0x0000000103e43305 UIKit`-[UIKeyboardImpl unmarkText:] + 180
  frame #13: 0x0000000103e45df6 UIKit`__59-[UIKeyboardImpl handleAcceptedCandidate:executionContext:]_block_invoke_2 + 39
```

backtrace for autocorrect english character

```
frame #6: 0x0000000102dfb109 Foundation`-[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 66
frame #7: 0x0000000104585ab8 UIKit`-[UITextField fieldEditorDidChange:] + 257
frame #8: 0x0000000104590cb7 UIKit`-[UITextInputController _sendDelegateChangeNotificationsForText:selection:] + 138
frame #9: 0x0000000104593281 UIKit`-[UITextInputController _insertText:fromKeyboard:] + 893
frame #10: 0x0000000104593bcd UIKit`-[UITextInputController insertText:] + 365
frame #11: 0x0000000103d1d728 UIKit`-[UIFieldEditor insertFilteredText:] + 800
frame #12: 0x000000010458a7d7 UIKit`-[UITextField insertFilteredText:] + 103
frame #13: 0x0000000103e48a83 UIKit`-[UIKeyboardImpl insertText:] + 125
frame #14: 0x0000000103e45278 UIKit`-[UIKeyboardImpl performKeyboardOutput:] + 496
frame #15: 0x0000000103e44e65 UIKit`__55-[UIKeyboardImpl handleKeyboardInput:executionContext:]_block_invoke_2 + 164
```

Comment: Where you add observer in view controller? I mean in which method?

Comment: When it is called twice, look at the `text` value of the text field. Is the value any different between the two calls?

Comment: @developer I have called it in init method.

Comment: @rmaddy Value and process both are different. There are two processes 1. when I select from  autocorrect Chinese characters in textfield and 2. when I enter english character from keyboard to textfield

Comment: You misunderstood me. You stated that when a user enters Chinese characters from autocorrect, your `textChanged:` method gets called twice, correct? I asking, when this happens, is the value of the text field's `text` different between these to calls?

Comment: @rmaddy I  got your question. You're correct and value doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

You might called `init` method twice.
Also do not forget to remove the observer `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification object:nil];` in `viewWillDisappear:`